# Is it possible to set up auto-scaling so that it always duplicates the most recent version of your main server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I know that you can create an image of your server as-is and setup auto-scaling on that, but what if I then make changes to my original server? Do I have to then make another snapshot of that and setup auto-scaling again?

Comment: Why would you make changes to your original server outside of repeatable automation?

Comment: I guess I have no clue what I'm doing in general.

Comment: What if you want to deploy a new feature or something like that? Am I in the totally wrong place right now?

Comment: You don't have to "set up" autoscaling again. You could capture an updated AMI and then modify the autoscaling launch configuration to use the new AMI then trigger replacement of existing instance as needed. It's also worth reading about [Instance Refresh](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-instance-refresh-for-ec2-auto-scaling/).

Comment: I see. So essentially anytime I upload some new code to my original server, I will have to create an new AMI. I think my pipeline is all wrong because my current configuration is not built for something like that. I'm constantly adding new features to the ec2 that I have running. I think I should probably scale up my server and worry about auto-scaling later.

Comment: There's a balance to be found between maintaining a [golden AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/appguide/ex-immute-gold-ami.html) and constantly patching instances. You have to find the right balance for your DevOps workflow. Worth reading [Application Maintenance Strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/managedservices/latest/appguide/aog-ams-app-maintain.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for configuring a server:

- Creating an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) with all software fully configured, or
- Having the instance configure itself via a startup script triggered via [User Data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

A fully-configured AMI is fast to startup, whereas a configuration script can take several minutes to configure the instance before the instance is ready to accept traffic.

In general, it is not considered good practice to "make changes to my original server" because there is no concept of an "original server". All instances are considered equal. Instead, the configuration should be created and tested on development servers separate to any production servers and then released by deploying *new* servers or by having an 'update' script intelligently run on existing servers. Some of these capabilities are provided by **AWS CodeDeploy**.